# Configure execution speed of steps in WebDriver Script like Selenium IDE Throttling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

So, in the Firefox Selenium IDE, you are able to "throttle" the script by adding a pause between each command using a slider from "Fast" to "Slow".  I was wondering if this can be simulated in a `Java WebDriver` script?  Everywhere I look uses `implicit waits` which I don't believe is the same thing.  What I want is more of an `automatic Thread.sleep` between commands.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a reason really for you to hard-code pauses in your test code.   If you code your tests correctly, using the right ExpectedConditions and exception handling, you shouldn't need to put pauses in your tests to get them to behave successfully.

If you actually want to throttle to slow down web performance, then you probably want to user [BrowserMob Proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/).

In theory, you could use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to listen for events and pause on them dynamically.   For example, I use AOP to pause a certain number of milliseconds between page transitions depending on how I configure it.

Instead of using Thread.sleep, which requires you handle the InteruptedException, I user [Selenium Sleeper class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Sleeper.html) (which might get deprecated in Selenium 3.0?)

Comment: Thanks!  Understandably, it's not something that I should do, it's just functionality that I want to mimic in the IDE in my automation and test scripts if possible.

Comment: yeah, what you are doing isn't super simple to do, but you have a couple options at least, depending on what sort of pauses you want.